# Abrir app o tienda con url

Tags: android, ionic, ios, google-play

Tengo una aplicación en Play Store y en AppStore pero quiero que para que más personas la descarguen poder enviar por Whatsapp un enlace para que si la persona tiene instalada la aplicación la abra y si no la tiene instalada que el enlace lleve a la tienda para que descargue la aplicación.

Estoy usando Ionic.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas tardes Nelson. ¿Qué has hecho hasta ahora? Cual es la duda?

Comment: Agregué el plugin de Deeplink en ionic pero no se como lo debo configurar si uso LazyLoading. Primero quiero hacer que por lo menos con un enlace que envie por Whatsapp abra la aplicación.

Comment: Hola @NelsonHernandez recuerda agregar en tus preguntas lo que hayas tratado o investigado, saludos!

Answer (score -1):

No se puede realizar con un solo enlace, puesto que no puedes tener acceso al registro de las apps instaladas. Sin embargo con dos enlaces podrias lograrlo usando deeplinks y las urls a las correspondientes tiendas (android o ios). Por ejemplo usando el siguiente mensaje:

> Abre la app desde aquí: **myApp://contenido** o descargala en android
>   desde aquí: **url-para-tienda-android** y para ios
>   **url-para-tienda-ios**

mas info de deeplinks [aquí](https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/)

Comment: En [esta web](https://www.yeeply.com/blog/deep-linking-aplicaciones-moviles/) encontré esto:
"2. Enlaces profundos diferidos (Deferred Deep Links)
En el caso de los enlaces profundos diferidos, si el usuario no tiene la aplicación instalada, el enlace dirigirá a la página de descarga de la aplicación en la ‘store’ respectiva. Una vez instalada la app podremos acceder directamente al contenido compartido."

Comment: Interesante @NelsonHernandez no habia revisado, entonces solo con el link inicial **myApp://contenido** estaria resulteo segun la web que comentas.

Comment: pero si escribo eso en Whatsapp no lo toma como un enlace, solo como texto.